# linux system environment variables and user environment variables

Tags: python, linux, environment-variables

I have been confused with the question that why user environment variables can't work if system environment variables existing.

Rencently i installed and configured the python2.7 in linux. There was a python version 2.6.7 in linux

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

so I had to set environment variable.
Through internet I obtained the means to set the path

```
vi ~/.bash_profile(vi ~/.bashrc)
#add export PATH=$PATH:path_python_installed
source /etc/profile
```

But I have no idea why it doen't work.
My solution is

```
#add alias python=path_python_installed/python
```

R installation was the same.

Comment: most linux distributaions have come with python 2 and 3 preinstalled.

Comment: just run `python` or `python3` on terminal.

Comment: as I remember `alias` affected only for current session, so after system reboot all applied changes will be avoided. Just use `PATH=$PATH:path_python_installed` and restart terminal

Answer (score 0):

If you have a path in $PATH which already contains the 2.6.7 version, it will find that binary first.

Try echo $PATH and see if any of those paths include the older Python binary. You might want to set PATH to;

export PATH=path_to_new_python:$PATH

Comment: I had done that before, but it doesn't work for next launch.

    echo $PATH
    /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/ sbin:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_01/bin:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_01/jre/bin:/home/zhangjw/bin:/home/zhangjw/Soft/R-3.1.1/bin

Comment: Add it to .bashrc. This gets read on every new shell. use 'which' to see which python binary would be called from the shell.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the new search path to the front of PATH:

```
 export PATH=/my/new/python/installation/bin:$PATH
```

When you enter `python` at the command prompt, the shell tries to find a file name python in any of the folders that are listed in $PATH. The first match will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `#add` in front of the export and the alias commands. # is used to start a comment in Bash script. Wherever you found these, he must have added the #add as simply a directive.

UPDATE: You will also want to do what Bernhard has mentioned in his answer.

Comment: I'm sorry for my script misleading you. Actually I din't use sigh #add.